# jEditable - Submit a Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jeditable

I'm pretty new to Jeditable and I was wondering if there is a way to generate and submit a custom form with multiple fields instead of just one field?

I've taken a look at this [tutorial](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-create-complex-editable-fields-jeditable-and-make-it-sending-all-form-content) for some hints and I've made a bit of progress. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea where you can save whatever has been edited in the form. Give the inputs in the form a certain class, call it "my_form". Create a button that initializes the my_form class with JEditable by creating a function called `makeEditable()`. Also make the Save button have a class which we'll call `save_button`.

```
$(function(){
    function makeEditable() {
        $(".my_form").editable('MyPhpPage.php', {
             // YOUR CUSTOMIZATION
             submit : '<button class="save_button">Save</button>',
        });

     makeEditable();
    });
```

You can finally send all the modified data with with a "Submit" button of class "save_button", and that's accomplished with `$('.my_form').find('.save_button').click();`.

This may be not robust enough for your form as you might want to create constraints such as require all of them to be non-empty. You then just need a bit more JQuery code to do so.